# Как получить список файлов из папки?

Tags: yii2

Как получить список файлов с определенным расширением из заданной папки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться хэлпером **FileHelper** и его методом **findFiles()**

Он выбирает все файлы и файлы в подпопапок в указанной директории.

[Ссылка на документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles()-detail)

Пример:

`$files=\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('/path/to');` -
Выбирает файлы в указанной директории.

`\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('.',['only'=>['*.php','*.txt']]);` - Выберет файлы из указанной директории с указанными расширениями.

`\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('.',['except'=>['*.php','*.txt']]);` - Выберет файлы из указанной директории кроме тех, что имеют указанные расширения.

`\yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('.',['recursive'=>FALSE]);` - **'recursive'=>FALSE** указывает на то, что не требуется перебирать еще и вложенные папки.